# Go back link without refresh

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

First let me say that my title not exactly explain what I mean.  The issue is I have created a jQuery table  to display video records.  Within the table there is a link to the video record display page.  I have a link on the display page `<a href="javascript: history.go(-1)"></a>` to return me back to the results page with the jQuery.  This page is laden with javascript, including dialog boxes, and everytime I link back to this page, it reloads and displays the dialog box content while loading before removing it from the screen.  I am wondering if there is anyway to redirect back to a cached page or another method to reduce the amount of loading so unnecessary information is not displayed during load.  Please and thank you for any help.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on things like the browser cache for functionality. Your back button shouldn't attempt to use `history.go`, it should be a link back to whatever page is logically the parent of the current page. You cannot rely on the order of `history`; a user may have loaded your page from a bookmark, or have history/caching disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Check the HTTP response headers being sent by your PHP page.  If it's telling the browser not to cache the page, then it may be forcing the browser to reload unnecessarily.  Default PHP headers normally tell the browser not to cache.  One way to check this is by using `curl` from the command line:

```
curl --head http://your.domain/foo.php
```

This tells you only the headers that your page would send.  Headers like `Expires`, `Cache-Control`, and `Pragma` involve browser caching.  For example, a typical PHP page on one of my sites has the following headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.0.4
Date: Tue, 26 Jul 2011 15:51:53 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=20
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=osumsgkcn7c1rb8udba33epek6; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
```

Comment: On second thought, I totally agree with @meagar's comment above, about not using `history.go()` at all.  But if you still wanted to use it, the headers are the first thing I'd check to address your problem.

Comment: I was only using history.go() because I thought it would help my issues with reloading the page after clicking the back link.  I just want to return back to the previous page without having to reload all the javascript/jquery.  Possible?

Comment: What about using JavaScript to set some cookies to preserve the state of your page on subsequent reloads?  jQuery has a `jquery.cookie.js` plugin that makes it really easy to interface with cookies.

Comment: Can you point me in the direction of an example on how to do this?  I've looked through the jQuery Cookie plugin and there is very little documentation, especially about preserving page states.  Thank you

Comment: For each item on your page whose state you want to save, you'll have to use that cookie plugin to save that item's state each time it changes.  And when the page loads, you'll also have to read the cookie and set the state accordingly.  I don't know of a guide offhand, but there's [a SO question here that might give you some clues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124039/toggle-and-preserve-state-with-jquery-and-cookies).

Answer (score 0):

OK, the way that a see your scenario:

1 - are you request pages doing using ajax/json

2 - you have a way to store the content loaded on the last page

So you can:

1 - load the current page using ajax + json, and store a copy of it on a variable (aka current)

2 - when the user click on a link (that will send him to another page), the content of current page (json) is stored on a variable (aka cache), and the new json overwrite the current variable value

3 - when the user click on back link, the page verify if there are any value on cache variable, if true load that variable, else, call the content from server.

This is a minimalists idea based on the example that I implemented here: http://neogamabbh.com.br/en